# Detect when an HTML5 video finishes

Tags: html, html5-video

How do you detect when a HTML5 `<video>` element has finished playing?

Comment: Very useful documentation with test page from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/HTML5VideoEventFlow/Listings/events_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010085-events_js-DontLinkElementID_5 All you wanted to know on HTML5 video events!

Answer (score 377, accepted):

You can add an event listener with 'ended' as first param

Like this :

```
<video src="video.ogv" id="myVideo">
  video not supported
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        // What you want to do after the event
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the only video."on end" event which works in the whole internet. Bravo!

Comment: Why do you check if e exists?

Comment: Works on Android Chrome in contrast to `onended`

Comment: @AllanStepps From what I can gather, the `if(!e) { e = window.event; }` statement that this answer originally included is IE-specific code for getting the latest event from within an event handler attached with `attachEvent` on early versions of IE. Since in this case, the handler is being attached with `addEventListener` (and those early versions of IE are irrelevant to people dealing with HTML5 video), it was completely unnecessary and I have removed it.

Comment: use this inside myHandler to refer to video,  if (this.currentTime == this.duration)

Comment: One point to note when using this method, Safari on the El Capitan verson of OS X  (10.11) does not catch the 'ended' event.  So in that case, I needed to use the 'timeupdate' event and then check for when this.current Time was equal to 0 again.

Comment: Also remember to set loop to false, otherwise the ended event won't be triggered.

Comment: @MarkAmery  if `e` argument does not exist, that means the function was called raw, like `myHandler()` rather than by a video element/object event. This distinction can be useful.

Answer (score 145):

Have a look at this *[Everything You Need to Know About HTML5 Video and Audio](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)* post at the Opera Dev site under the "I want to roll my own controls" section.

This is the pertinent section:

```
<video src="video.ogv">
     video not supported
</video>
```

then you can use:

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
      /*Do things here!*/
    };
</script>
```

`onended` is a HTML5 standard event on all media elements, see the [HTML5 media element (video/audio) events](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-ended) documentation.

Comment: I've tried to catch "ended" event exactly the same way, as you presented, but this event is not firing. I'm under Safari 5.0.4 (6533.20.27)

Comment: @AntonAL: I'd post this as a new question if you are having issues.

Comment: @All: You can do it like this as well.  <video class="video_player" id="video" poster="images/video-pc.jpg" tabindex="0" height="100%" onended="myHandler()">

Comment: @AlastairPitts This is not valid on Chrome. Darkroro's answer is the only way I got it to work with Chrome. This still worked on Firefox.

Comment: Dead links. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp => Media Events

Comment: This is the one that works for me. Adding event listener 'ended' didn't work.

Answer (score 39):

JQUERY

```
$("#video1").bind("ended", function() {
   //TO DO: Your code goes here...
});
```

HTML

```
<video id="video1" width="420">
  <source src="path/filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Event types [HTML Audio and Video DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

Comment: -1. `.on()` has been preferred over `.bind()` since jQuery 1.7, which was released in 2011. Also, please format your code properly.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply add `onended="myFunction()"` to your video tag.

```
<video onended="myFunction()">
  ...
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function myFunction(){
    console.log("The End.")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple approach which triggers when the video ends.

```
<html>
<body>

    <video id="myVideo" controls="controls">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        etc ...
    </video>

</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {

        alert('The End');

    })

</script>
</html>
```

In the 'EventListener' line substitute the word 'ended' with 'pause' or 'play' to capture those events as well.

Comment: You have a syntax error in this JS code. 
Missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example, I hope it helps =).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video id="myVideo" controls="controls">
  <source src="your_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="your_video_file.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) { e = window.event; }
        alert("Video Finished");
    }
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add listener all video events nicluding `ended, loadedmetadata, timeupdate` where `ended` function gets called when video ends

```js
$("#myVideo").on("ended", function() {
   //TO DO: Your code goes here...
      alert("Video Finished");
});

$("#myVideo").on("loadedmetadata", function() {
      alert("Video loaded");
  this.currentTime = 50;//50 seconds
   //TO DO: Your code goes here...
});


$("#myVideo").on("timeupdate", function() {
  var cTime=this.currentTime;
  if(cTime>0 && cTime % 2 == 0)//Alerts every 2 minutes once
      alert("Video played "+cTime+" minutes");
   //TO DO: Your code goes here...
  var perc=cTime * 100 / this.duration;
  if(perc % 10 == 0)//Alerts when every 10% watched
      alert("Video played "+ perc +"%");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <video id="myVideo" controls="controls">
    <source src="your_video_file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="your_video_file.mp4" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

</body>

</html>
```