#  Need to trigger an event on a video ending

Tags: javascript, video, triggers

Working on switching from Flash to a flash player/html5 video player hybrid solution. Using video.js player. I am looking to hide the player and show a div block with javascript upon video finishing. Would anyone know how to trigger this? I have a SWF container and a video container. Anyone have any suggestions?

www.friedmanllp.com/home3.php

Following code:

```
    <div class="video-js-box">
        <!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="545" height="380" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/video.jpg">
          <source src="http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/intro.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
          <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="545" height="380" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/video.jpg", {"url": "http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/intro.mp4","autoPlay":true,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />
            <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. -->
            <img src="http://www.friedmanllp.com/video/video.jpg" width="545" height="380" alt="Poster Image"
              title="No video playback capabilities." />
          </object>
        </video>
        <!-- Download links provided for devices that can't play video in the browser. -->
    </div>

    <div style="display:none; width:545px; height:380px; overflow:hidden;">
        <div class="practices_link" style="float:left; margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px; cursor:pointer;"><img class="practices_on" style="margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px;" src="images/alt/practices_on.jpg" /><img class="practices_off" style="display:none; margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px;" src="images/alt/practices_off.jpg" /></div><div style="float:left; margin-bottom:1px; width:355px; height:17px;"><img src="images/alt/blank_alt.gif" style="width:355px; height:17px;"></div><div class="services_link" style="float:left; margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px;"><img class="services_off" style="margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px; cursor:pointer;" src="images/alt/services_off.jpg" /><img class="services_on" style="display:none; margin-bottom:1px; width:95px; height:17px; cursor:pointer;" src="images/alt/services_on.jpg" /></div>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="practices" style="float:left; top:0; left:0; position:relative;">
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=1"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=5"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/2.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=13"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/3.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=2"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/4.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=18"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/5.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=28"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/6.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="services" style="float:left; top:-360px; left:545px; position:relative;">
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=21"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/7.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=7"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/8.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=29"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/9.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=30"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/10.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=14"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/11.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="http://www.friedmanllp.com/articles.php?pcode=17"><img style="margin-bottom:1px;" src="images/alt/12.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: HTML5 videos should have an "ended" event that fires when the video ends.

Comment: Have you considered [html5][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events

Comment: Have you considered [html5][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events

Comment: I keep trying to post that as an answer, but it keeps posting as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking to hide the player and show a div block with javascript upon video finishing.

Look in the docs of your video player whether it has an event for it; if it doesn't, change players.

[JPlayer has events, for example](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type).

Comment: I got it using the following:

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example_video_1').bind("ended", function(){ 
   $('.video-js-box').css('display','none');
   $('#slider').css('display','block');
 });
});

Comment: I got it using the following:

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example_video_1').bind("ended", function(){ 
   $('.video-js-box').css('display','none');
   $('#slider').css('display','block');
 });
});

Although I don't think this will work as a total cross browser solution. IE7 and IE8 do not support the video tag. I found a hack project in the works, but it's not far enough along to use yet.

And the flash file that I was trying to not have to rebuild, I will most likely have to from scratch. And use image slides as a fallback for iPads and iPhones.