# Determine when HTML5 audio is paused or track is finished using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I am working on an HTML5 audio tag and I want to trigger an event when the song is finished. Is this possible with jQuery?

My jQuery code is:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

var music = new Audio("sample.mp3");
$('#play').click(function(){
    music.play();
});

$('#pause').click(function(){
 music.pause();
});

         });
```

My HTML5 is:

```
<input type="button" value="Play" id="play" />
<input type="button" value="Pause" id=pause" />
```

Comment: Related: [Need to trigger an event on a video ending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588921/7588975#7588975)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use HTML 5 **onended** event handler

```
<audio src="sample.mp3" onended="yourFunction()"></audio>
```

For jQuery bind **ended** event handler

```
 $(music).bind("ended", function(){ ... });
```

Comment: thanks for reply actually i want to trigger it through jquery how its possible with jquery?

Comment: For jQuery bind ended event handler. Something like, `$(music).bind("ended", function(){ ... });`

Comment: @danny what browser are you using?

Comment: i just tested $(music).bind("ended", function(){ ... }); it works fine i am using chrome. I have replaced the code music.addEventListener("ended", function() { }); to $(music).bind("ended", function(){ alert('fired');}); its perfect thanks.

Comment: Emmanule if you edit your reply and add audio status function etc file is paused or stopped etc it would help lots of people.

Answer (score 3):

```
.bind("ended", function(){ });
```

Or

```
 music.addEventListener("ended", function() { });
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working. i dont know whats wrong i have used music.bind("ended, function(){});

Comment: music.addEventListener("ended", function() { }); is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio class="ah-audio-player" preload="auto">
  <source type="audio/mpeg" src="sound.mp3">
</audio>
```

-

```
var audio_player = $('.ah-audio-player');
audio_player.on('ended', function () {
    alert('end');
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answer *answers* the posted question