# HTML5 audio playlist - how to play a second audio file after the first has ended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

How could we make some audio in html5 play after another one has finished?

I have tried with jquery `delay()` function but it wont work at all, is it possible using `pause()` in html5 audio with  timer instead ? For example, `pause('500',function(){});`?

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652031/how-to-find-audio-is-paused-or-track-finished-in-jquery-html5-audio

Comment: yes, that not for delay(), what i mean is how could the 2nd audio file playing after the first one is finish,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a JSLinted, unobtrusive Javascript **example** demonstrating how to handle and use the `ended` [mediaevent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events). In your particular situation, you would trigger playback of the second audio file in your `ended` event handler.

You can use the code below or [run the test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/jwyMH/).

Click an item in the playlist to begin playback. After one audio ends, the next will begin.

markup: (note the deliberate avoidance of whitespace between `<li>` elements - this is to simplify traversing the DOM with `nextSibling`.)

```
<audio id="player"></audio>

<ul id="playlist"><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%201%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space 1</li><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%202%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space 2</li><li data-ogg="http://www.lunerouge.org/sons/sf/LRWeird%203%20by%20Lionel%20Allorge.ogg">Space Lab</li></ul>

<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

script:

```
// globals
var _player = document.getElementById("player"),
    _playlist = document.getElementById("playlist"),
    _stop = document.getElementById("stop");

// functions
function playlistItemClick(clickedElement) {
    var selected = _playlist.querySelector(".selected");
    if (selected) {
        selected.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    clickedElement.classList.add("selected");

    _player.src = clickedElement.getAttribute("data-ogg");
    _player.play();
}

function playNext() {
    var selected = _playlist.querySelector("li.selected");
    if (selected && selected.nextSibling) {
        playlistItemClick(selected.nextSibling);
    }
}

// event listeners
_stop.addEventListener("click", function () {
    _player.pause();
});
_player.addEventListener("ended", playNext);
_playlist.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
        playlistItemClick(e.target);
    }
});​


​
```

Comment: thanks Lloyd, that working find, thanks, but i'm not using a ul li child emelement dom, it like a otomatic playing in bakground (background music for some little game)

Comment: this is not intended to be an exact solution for your problem (how can it be, i know nothing about your game).. this is an example to demonstrate handling the `ended` media event - this event fires when playback has ended.. in the handler for this event, write some code to play your second audio file.

Comment: thanks, at last it solved my problem, using some of your code make it clear, thanks dude

Answer (score 11):

If this is your audio tag:

```
<audio id="player" src="someAudio.mp3"/>
```

then adding an event listener to it for the "ended" event will make it possible to change the source and play your next sound.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("player");
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    audio.src = "nextAudio.mp3";
    audio.play();
});
```

Comment: this gives a promise exception "the play request was interrupted by new load request"

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help you ...

[html5 audio player - jquery toggle click play/pause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988050/html5-audio-player-jquery-toggle-click-play-pause)

so instead of a click you should use a setTimeout, or a setInterval, which ever you feel more comfortable with to check constantly for the `.paused==false` I think you might be able to check if it is finished by checking videos's length and compare it with max length, which == end of file.

Comment: how do we made the audio playing after the first one ? is that posible ? when the first audio is finish then the 2nd one continue playing?

Comment: @Val is there any advantage using this method over responding to the `ended` event?

Comment: well I can only offer my knowledge :) I didnt know about the ended event.