# HTML5 JQuery Audio Player

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I am making a jQuery audio player, get audio source files from HTML5  tag. Everything works fine with play, pause, next and previous button. Now I am looking for a solution to let the player continue playing all musics automatically after one music is finished without clicking on the next button. Does anyone know any tricks to loop through all musics and let it play one by one? Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality is not provided by the audio tag, but you could hook into the 'ended' event to trigger the next track.

It's already been answered here,

[HTML5 audio playlist - how to play a second audio file after the first has ended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326288/html5-audio-playlist-how-to-play-a-second-audio-file-after-the-first-has-ended)