# Javascript/html audio problems

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm having some problems in my code. To begin, I would like for a song to play after a song I am playing ends (with the audio tag).

```
<audio id="batmansong1">
  <source src="Songs/nanananabatman.m4a">
</audio>
<button id="play" onclick="document.getElementById('batmansong1').play()"><img src="Buttons/play.jpg" height="40" width="40"></button>
<button id="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('batmansong1').pause()"><img src="Buttons/pause.jpg" height="40" width="40"></button>
```

As you can see, the buttons will play or pause the first audio clip. However, I want them to also pause and play the second audio clip when it starts playing.

Comment: WHat have you tried ? The code you have currently will only play the song once when the button is clicked.

Comment: The code I pasted would help you play sound. Please be clearer with your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 audio playlist - how to play a second audio file after the first has ended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326288/html5-audio-playlist-how-to-play-a-second-audio-file-after-the-first-has-ended)

Comment: I've tried using Jquery and adding 
 
$("#play").click(function(){
 $("body").append("<audio id='batmansong1'><source src='Songs/batmanloop.m4a'></audio>");
 })

However, no sound from the second file came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons will still be working when doing this. You can add an eventlistener that checks if te `<audio>` element ended playing. Then you just set the next source and start playing again. (BTW you'd better not use inline javacript and old html styling (I mean width="40" and such, just use CSS))

all the code below is in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdwwQ/)

JS:

```
player = document.getElementById('batmansong1');
player.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    if (player.src == 'link/to/your/next/file.m4a') return; //check if we have already set the new src, as this function is called EVERY TIME your audio file ends.
    player.src = 'link/to/your/next/file.m4a';
    player.play();
});

document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('batmansong1').pause();
});
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('batmansong1').play();
});
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="batmansong1" src="Songs/nanananabatman.m4a"></audio>
<button id="play">
    <img src="Buttons/play.jpg" />
</button>
<button id="pause">
    <img src="Buttons/pause.jpg" />
</button>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

If you want to know anything else, feel free to ask!

Answer (score -1):

```
//It should work for html 5 surpport browsers

function htmlfiveMedia(){
    document.getElementById('player').play();
}


//in your html
<audio id="player" src="../jizadmin/sounds/new_message.wav"></audio>


OR

IF THE BROWSER DOES NOT SUPPORT AUDIO TAG TRY THIS BELOW

//This function is going to play sound
function explorerMedia()
{
    $('embed').remove();

    $("<embed src='../jizadmin/sounds/new_message.wav' autostart='true' hidden='true' height='1' width='1'>").insertAfter('hr');
}



//add an <hr> below your page

Hope this would help
```

Comment: I'm not using embed, I'm using <audio> and <source>

Comment: ok sorry. just add it there in case you fall back to some old school browsers