# click event on html5 fullscreen video

Tags: jquery, html, events, video, click

I'm trying to manipulate the HTML5 video tag with jQuery.
I only need all this to work in Chrome for now.

I'm stuck with something : when my video is played in fullscreen (using webkitEnterFullScreen() on the video), I want to be able to exit the fullscreen mode as soon as the user clicks **anywhere** on the video.
No mater how I try, I can't seem to be able to capture **any** click even when the video is playing fullscreen.

```
$('myvideo').click(...
$(document).click(...
$(window).click(...
```

none of them do anything when in fullscreen.

Is it a normal behavior ?

I don't want to use libraries like videojs if I don't have to.
Thank you for your help

edit : simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tWTrT/7/ the console won't trace anything as soon as you enter fullscreen mode.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events