# jQuery - Detect click in certain pixel area, then execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a div, let's call it `#videodiv` that includes an HTML5 video player ([SublimeVideo](http://sublimevideo.net), but that may be irrelevant information). On page load, `#videodiv` is only 100px. When a user clicks anywhere within `#videodiv`, I'd like for jQuery to expand the div to 250px.

You may be saying -- that's as simple as a jQuery function comes, just use click then animate! And you'd be right, except...

**Here's the problem:** The HTML5 video player that is contained within `#videodiv` and that fills the entire div captures all clicks that occur. This is done to trigger the play/pause function for the player, but subsequently disallows any programmer to set a jQuery click function for the containing div.

Luckily in this situation, `#videodiv`is a 100% full body-width div and has an exact height of 100px. So, bearing in mind the problem above, the alternative would be to figure out if we can capture any clicks **within the HTML document** (rather than the div) that occur in the top 100 pixels of the page, then trigger the function.

*In other words, how can we use jQuery to detect mouse clicks anywhere within the first 100 pixels of a page, then animate the div `videodiv` to 250px?*

Alternative/better solutions are *absolutely* more than welcome, but jQuery is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question with the following answer provided on a separate StackOverflow question, located here: [Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events)

It's a matter of only two steps:

1. Detect `onplay` with jQuery
2. Run jQuery function

As you see, HTML5 is extremely simplistic; I only wish the documentation was more easily accessible/searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work - change the width and height values to match your needs. `pageX` is lateral and `pageY` is vertical so I just mapped a 100x100 space in the top left corner. Change that to fit your needs as well:

```
// Bind the click event to the body - any static parent container will do
$('body').on('click', function(e) {

    // Fire the callback if the click was in the top 100px by 100px
    if (e.pageX <= 100 && e.pageY <= 100) {

        // Prevent crazy animations and redundant handling
        $(this).off('click'); 

        // Scale the video to the appropriate size
        $('#videodiv').animate({
            width  : '250px',
            height : '250px'
         }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bKm4U/

Comment: Just set that video sizing logic as a function and bind it to both the body click as well as the video.play() event. Then both actions will size the div.