# HTML5 video redirection

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Basically what I'm trying to do is make the video redirect to a different web page after it's finished playing (very similar to what YouTube uses for Playlists). I've tried doing a bit of research before asking this type of question but nothing seems to be working out for me.

Here's the code:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="854" height="480"
  poster="images/thumbnailbackgrounds/AE-DageSide.jpg"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="files/Clip1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using Video.JS for this, you should have a look at their docs:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/index.md

Specifically, the API section:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

In the "Events" section, it says:

**ended**

`Fired when the end of the media resource is reached. currentTime == duration`

So you'd need to get a reference to your player (also on that page):

```
var myPlayer = videojs("example_video_1");
```

and then listen for the ended event, and redirect from there:

```
function endedFunction(){
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/';
}

myPlayer.on("eventName", endedFunction);
```

Comment: Thank you M Sost and Bram Vanroy for the helpful posts. The issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

As borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events#answer-2741527), try the following. And you don't need video.js for this.
**HTML**

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="854" height="480"
  poster="images/thumbnailbackgrounds/AE-DageSide.jpg"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="files/Clip1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByClassName("video-js");

    // Or select element by HTML tag
    // var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function() {
      window.location.href = "www.yoururl.com";
    }
</script>
```

Ought to work.

Comment: This will also work, although it should be noted that Video.JS wraps the video/alters the DOM, changing the ID for the video element.  See example here: http://www.videojs.com/.  The source element has an ID of home_video, but after page load, the video element then gets an ID of home_video_html5_api