# playing event in html5 video TAG

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have tried like this

```
document.getElementById('myVID').onplaying = alert("Playback started");
```

But, the alert is not coming. I have tested it in chrome. Is there any issue in this code?. Otherwise this event is not supported.

Comment: `Element.onplaying` expects a function, and `alert()` **returns** nothing (`undefined`).

Answer (score 2):

***Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E7FhU/***

I would say change your code to be like this because as @Passerby said, alert returns `undefined` and you need to assign a function. Additionally, this can be accomplished with simple javascript.

```
    <script>
        var video = document.getElementById('myVID');

        video.onplaying = function(e) {
          /*Do things here!*/
          alert("hello video");
        }
    </script>
```

When you click play the alert is displayed.

**References:**

- **[Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events)**

Comment: I have written the code as below, I am getting the alert "Load Start" but not getting the alert "hello video"

<script language="JavaScript">

var video = document.getElementById('myVID');

video.onloadstart = alert("Load Start");

video.onplaying = function(e) {
  /*Do things here!*/
  alert("hello video");
}

</script>

Comment: @Kannan This is from an error caused by trying to assign `undefined` to onloadstart. When you assign a function to both, the onplaying event work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/GsbhY/