# Unable to bind events in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html5-video, jquery-events

Why aren't events being binded in my simple JQuery code? - http://pastebin.com/24J6q5G0

Relevant sections:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video controls preload autoplay>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>

<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video controls preload="none">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vid0 = $(document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrapper')[0]);
    var vid1 = $(document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrapper')[1]);
    vid1.hide();
    vid0.bind('ended', function() {
        vid1.show();
    })
})
```

(I have been following along with [Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events))

Comment: The event needs to be done on the `source` tag not the `video` tag, so changing it to: `vid0.children().bind('ended', function() {` works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I used (think there was only one [wrong] answer at the time) was:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vid0 = $(document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrapper')[0]);
    var vid1 = $(document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrapper')[1]);
    vid1.hide();
    vid0.children().bind('ended', function() {    // Note this line
        vid1.show();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ended event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/ended) is not propagated(bubbled), so try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrappers = $('.videoWrapper');
    wrappers.eq(1).hide()
    wrappers.eq(0).find('video').bind('ended', function() {
        wrappers.eq(1).show();
    })
})
```

In your case you are binding the event to the wrapping `div` element, but the `ended` event is not bubbled to the parent element which means your handler will never get executed.

Comment: The `.eq`, does that have similar complexity to a simple array access?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser95 the problem is again you need to wrap it using jQuery

Comment: To repeat my question, is there any different between simple array access and `.eq` in terms of computational complexity and performance?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the events for HTML5 video fire on the `video` element, so you're attaching to the wrong element. Also, your'e method of creating jQuery selectors is a bit odd. Try this:

```
var $vid0 = $('.videoWrapper video').eq(0);
var $vid1 = $('.videoWrapper video').eq(1);
$vid1.parent().hide();
$vid0.bind('ended', function() {
    $vid1.parent().show();
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ERW6V/)

Answer (score -1):

The reason it's not working is because your vid0 is the wrapper div and the `ended` event needs the `video` tag.

Here is a working demo fix: http://jsfiddle.net/

I added `#video0` and `#video1` to the `video` tag.