# How to track if a video on a HTML 5 page has finished

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, responsive-design

I'm beginner and barely know HTML5 and CSS.

What I want is that after video on the page finishes, it should redirect to next page. 
I have a button on the page to take to next page.

```
<center>
<div id="vid_div1">
<video src="media/video/01.mp4" video id="myVideo" autoplay preload="auto" width="1000" height="600" data-setup="{}">

</video>
</div>
```

```
<ul class="style btn_close">
<li><a href="index_2.html" class="btn_close">Skip</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's an "ended" event, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events

Answer (score 0):

Use `onended` in Javascript.

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
      window.location = "index_2.html";
    }
</script>
```