# Load video then run script?

Tags: jquery

Here's my dilema, and I've searched to no avail.

I have a need to load and play an mp4 video once they page is fully loaded, then once that video is done I'd like to run a script to fade there div container of them video is in out to effectively get rid of it. Think of this as an intro video that plays, then gets removed.

I know this is possible with flash, but I'd prefer not to use flash if possible. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Josh

Comment: If you know the video lengths beforehand and your scenario does not allow the user to extend the required display length (e.g. pause the video), you could work with setTimeout. - i.e. in case you display advertisement or intro videos. For more complex scenarios you could take a look at this open source HTML5 video playback API at https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/api/vjs.Player.md for example.

Comment: Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript: take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events)

If I have understood correctly what you want to do, you basically need to remove the DOM element containing the video once it ends:

```
<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
      var parent = video.parentNode;
      if (parent) {
         parent.removeChild(video);
      }
    };
</script>
```

Assuming you only have one video TAG in your page (otherwise you can use document.getElementById)

Comment: Since he tagged his question jQuery, he could as well use `$("#videoID").get(0).onended(function(){$(this).fadeOut().then(function(){$(this).remove();});});` or something similar.

Comment: That would remove the video on end, but what about the parent element? How would I fade that out?

Comment: As Chris suggested, you can use jQuery `fadeOut()` method: `$(parent).fadeOut()` just before (or after) `parent.removeChild(video);`
If you don't want to use external libraries, you can always exploit `setInterval` to create an animation on `parent.style.opacity`