# Detecting end of video with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, video, event-listener

I have three videos that I am trying to detect when they end, and then navigate to another page.

The function seems to only work for the first video `$vid1` and nothing happens to the `$vid2` and `$vid3` videos.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/how-do-you-detect-html5-video-events), and sourced my code from there.

*(I noticed in a comment that it stated that the 'correct' answer doesn't work in chrome)*

How would I go about making this work for all videos?

**JS**

```
//variables
var $vid1 = document.getElementById("vid1");
var $vid2 = document.getElementById("vid2");  
var $vid3 = document.getElementById("vid3");

//functions
function Redirect1() {
    window.location.replace('ExamplePage1');
}

function Redirect2() {
    window.location.replace('ExamplePage2');
}

function Redirect3() {
    window.location.replace('ExamplePage3');
}

//events  

$vid1.addEventListener("ended", Redirect1, false);
$vid2.addEventListener("ended", Redirect2, false);
$vid3.addEventListener("ended", Redirect3, false);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoResult vidOne">
   <video id="vid1" controls>
     <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>

<div class="videoResult vidTwo">
   <video id="vid2" controls>
      <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>

<div class="videoResult vidThree">
   <video id="vid3" controls>
      <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working for the other videos, when the page gets changed as soon as the first video ends? Also note that you define the `Redirect2` function twice.

Comment: Thank you for noticing my typo, I corrected my spelling mistake.
And the videos have the controls on them so I have the ability to select which video to play in what ever order @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: But that's my point - the order is irrelevant. As soon as the first video ends (no matter if that's video1, 2, or 3) the page will be redirected.

Comment: That's actually what I want to happen. The videos are on the home page, As soon as the first video ends (whether it be video1, video2 or video3) it will redirect to another page. The page it is being redirected to has the option to navigate back to the home page - hopefully this makes sense @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

May be, try this?

```
//functions
function Redirect1() {
    window.location.replace('./ExamplePage1');
}

function Redirect2() {
    window.location.replace('./ExamplePage2');
}

function Redirect2() {
    window.location.replace('./ExamplePage3');
}
```

Comment: @MackieeE That's why I removed it.\

Comment: I have gone ahead and added the './' before the page names yet there is still no luck.

- I just went and replace the pages with other URLs like, facebook, google and youtube to see if that would work. Yet only the first function is working? @praveenkumar

Comment: @Jargonaut_ Can you try changing the order of the functions and let me know if still only the first one is working?

Comment: I've tried to create a JS fiddle to try make this easier, but it isn't allowing me to save the fiddle. So here is a code pen -http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNVZdd

I will let you know when I've arranged the order of the functions. Thanks for your help @praveenkumar

Comment: Sure. I will have a look at it @Jargonaut_!

Comment: I changed the order of the functions and placed `Redirect2` above `Redirect1` - and it changed! `Redirect1` no longer works and `Redirect2` now works. @praveenkumar

Comment: Grrr... That's crazy!

Comment: Would you have any other suggestions on how to overcome this problem? @praveenkumar

Comment: I am totally clueless buddy!

Comment: Damn. Thanks for talking a look for me though :) - if you have a light bulb moment in the near future , be sure to get back to me ha

Comment: I have checked my console log, and it says "cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null @praveenkumar

Comment: Why do you use `eventListener` now?

Comment: I've used the `addEventListener` the whole time for this bit of code? Should I not be using the `addEventListener` something else instead? @praveenkumar

Comment: Sorry forgot. Checked it, but you are using by ID right?

Comment: Yes, I am using `.getElementById();` @praveenkumar