# Change Banner after video is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, bxslider

We have usecase where we have 4 banners, each banner contains the video which is played using `HTML5 video player`.

We are using bx-slider for making the slides, but we want to have functionality where slide is automatically change after video is played. I have searched lot on google but no straight implementation is found. I have also tried to include `fitvids.js`, but still no success.

Is there any way around to get this problem resolved?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.:**

1. Each Video is of different length.

Answer (score 0):

Its Pretty Simple i think. 
All you need is to bind you movement clicks on

Video end Events.

You can find video end events info here...

[Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

in your handler function just move the slider and call play method of next video.

I could do the whole thing with code for you... But i think you should try this yourself first.

Comment: You're right, `ended` event is the way to go, but you could have included it in your answer. Also, I do agree OP should try it himself first but instead of linking to another question in your answer, it is preferable to flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: thanks bro. i am new to this whole stackflow thing :D i dint know that..