# Video how to play two videos in one video element with <embed>

Tags: html, windows, vbscript

I'm trying to make a web page that plays some videos in random and indefinite with **VBScript** and the tag `<embed>`.I have found an example but use JavaScript and HTML5, attachment link.

[HTML5 video how to play two videos in one video element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32335076/html5-video-how-to-play-two-videos-in-one-video-element)

```html
<video id="myvideo"width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="images\s1.mp4" type="video/mp4" showcontrols="0" loop="true" autostart="true"/>
    <embed src="images\s2.mp4"type="video/mp4" showcontrols="0" loop="true" autostart="true"/>  
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<embed>` tags are only used for embedding objects like Shockwave Flash.
`<video>` tags do not support `<embed>` tags.

You should only use `<src>` tags.

Also - add the `autoplay` and `loop` tags in the `video` element, not in the `src`:

```html
<video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" autoplay loop>
    <src="images\s1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <src="images\s2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>    
</video>
```

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have reviewed and was using IE 8 that does not support that tag. Now that I have updated to IE 11 I have not been able to make it play the video.

Comment: `src` is an attribute of the `source` element/tag. cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source