# Playing Video on Vaadin

Tags: video, vaadin7

I'm playing an mp4 video on my Vaadin application but have a few issues:

- Would like to listen to when it ends so I can close the window I used to display it.

Here's my code so far:

```
    //Display video
    ThemeResource fileResource = new ThemeResource("videos/intro.mp4");
    Video vd = new Video();
    vd.setAutoplay(true);
    vd.setSource(fileResource);
    vd.setResponsive(false);
    vd.setReadOnly(true);
    vd.setSizeFull();
    Window intro = new Window();
    intro.setContent(vd);
    intro.setHeight(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    intro.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    intro.center();
    intro.setModal(true);
    addWindow(intro);
    vd.play();
```

Sadly I was unable to find much information on this component. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880950/7655834) with Vaadin's [component extension](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html#gwt.extension.connector).

You need connector class which adds simple JS event listener proposed in cited answer:

```
@Connect(VideoEndedExtension.class)
public class VideoEndedConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {

    @Override
    protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
        addVideoEndedListener(((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget().getElement());
    }

    private void onVideoEnded() {
        getRpcProxy(VideoEndedRpc.class).onVideoEnded();
    }

    private native void addVideoEndedListener(Element el)
    /*-{
          var self = this;
          el.addEventListener('ended', $entry(function(e) {
              self.@your.package.VideoEndedConnector::onVideoEnded()();
          }), false);

    }-*/;
}
```

(you need to change `your.package` to the package which contains `VideoEndedConnector` class)

when event occurs the server is informed with the use of RPC:

```
public interface VideoEndedRpc extends ServerRpc {
    void onVideoEnded();
}
```

the last part is extension which registers RPC on the server side and handles incoming calls:

```
public class VideoEndedExtension extends AbstractExtension {

    private List<VideoEndedListener> videoEndedListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public interface VideoEndedListener extends Serializable {
        void onVideoEnded();
    }

    public void extend(Video video) {
        super.extend(video);
        registerRpc(new VideoEndedRpc() {

            @Override
            public void onVideoEnded() {
                for (VideoEndedListener listener : videoEndedListeners) {
                    listener.onVideoEnded();
                }               
            }
        });
    }

    public void addVideoEndedListener(VideoEndedListener listener) {
        if (listener != null) {
            videoEndedListeners.add(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

you can use it with your `Video` component:

```
Video v = new Video("video", new ExternalResource("link.to.video"));
VideoEndedExtension ext = new VideoEndedExtension();
ext.extend(v);
ext.addVideoEndedListener(new VideoEndedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        Notification.show("Video ended");
    }
});
```

If you want to read more about Vaadin's extensions check [this guide](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+an+UI+extension).

Native JavaScript part uses GWT's JavaScript Native Interface, if it seems weird for you, you can read more about it [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

Comment: I'll give it a try but have one question, I'm not clear what you mean with this: (you need to change you package from your.package). I mean I know what you mean but not sure which package are you referring to. Is this the package of the UI class?

Comment: It's the package of `VideoEndedConnector` class, I forgot to add the class name in the answer, now it should be more understandable.

Comment: Got an error compiling: [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/.../video/VideoEndedExtension.java'
         [ERROR] Line 37: No source code is available for type com.vaadin.ui.Video; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 28: No source code is available for type com.vaadin.server.AbstractExtension; did you forget to inherit a required module? Any idea?

Comment: Are you placing `VideoEndedExtension` in `client` package? It seems that GWT tries to compile it. Only `VideoEndedConnector` and `VideoEndedRpc` should be placed in `client` package.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by client package.

Comment: As described in [docs (bottom of the page)](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-extension.html#gwt.extension.connector), client-side classes need to be placed under a `client` package, so they can be compiled to JS and included in widgetset. It seems that `VideoEndedExtension` is placed in that package and GWT tries to compile it. I got the same error as you when I moved it there and tried to recompile my widgetset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147981/discussion-between-javydreamercsw-and-m-czerwinski).

Comment: After a painful session with Czerwinski (not painful because of him, because of Vaadin) I got it working with this answer. Thanks Czerwinski for the time you took to troubleshoot this.