# How would I use JavaScript to remove a video after it finishes playing?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Here is my HTML section..

```
<section id ="information">
  <video id ="videoName" width="800" height="400" controls 
   onplay="myAnimationPicture()"">
<source src="video/videoName.mp4" ; type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</section>
```

Here is my Javascript section...
document.getElementById('videoName').addEventListener('ended',deleteVideo,false);

```
function deleteVideo(e) 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('videoName');// What you 
    want to do after the event
    elem.remove();
}
```

Please let me know if it is even possible. What I eventually want to try and accomplish is after the user watches the video, the video is removed and is replaced with a horizontal menu for stats information.

Thank you,

Josh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

Comment: elem.onended = function() {
   // The audio has ended
};

Comment: So with everything suggested and offered to me, nothing is working to remove the video. Maybe it is browser specific but I may just move the menu bar below the video for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('videoName').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    //remove video here
    //add menu here
}
```

Which attaches a callback function (myHandler) that gets triggered after the video is done.

Comment: I have tried this but I think I'm not getting my "remove video" code correct.                                              
                                                                                          
     function myHandler(e)                                                            
     {                                                                                            
        e.target.parentNode(e.target);
        or   e.deleteVideo.target(e.target);

Comment: Try e.target.remove() or e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target). You could always set the parent containers inner html to ""

Answer (score 0):

Get the parent event target and remove the child ('#videoName')

```
function deleteVideo(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target)
}
```