# Fade in icon when video html5 ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to fade in an icon when video finish, but nothing.

**Html**

```
<video>
    <source src="">
</video>
<div class="icon"></div>
```

**First Try**

```
$("video").on("ended", function() { 
       $(".icon").fadeIn;
});
```

**Second try**

```
$('video').parent().on("ended", function() {
    if($(this).children("video").get(0).paused) { 
        $(this).children(".icon").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Actually has `onclick` event working fine

```
$("video").parent().on("click", function() {         
        $(this).children(".icon").fadeToggle(); 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

Comment: i always get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" in console with this solution, maybe i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
<video id="myVideo">
    <source src="">
</video>
<div class="icon"></div>

var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onended = function() {
    alert("The video has ended");  //Just to verify if the event is trapped
    $(".icon").fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: I think its fadeIn(). Anyway its working fine if i use getElementById, but if i use getElementsByClass doesnt work, or if i use getElementByTagName. Anyway why my code doesnt work? i cant understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way

```
    document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended',function() {
           $(".icon").fadeIn();
    },false);
```