# How to display a div element when HTML5 video ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I've been trying to do the following on my website's main page : a video in fullscreen plays (no controls, no loop, muted, autoplays, stored locally) and when it ends, the video is hidden and a div element shows.

I'm used to working with HTML and CSS but not so much JavaScript, so what I've done thus far is put the video, and used a checkbox to hide/show the elements (as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp)) and then tried to modify it so it would detect when the video ends, but I can't make it work.

The code I'm using is probably wrong, as it was meant for a checkbox, but I've also tried the solutions written [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes) and it seems like the issue comes from the function used to detect when the video ends not working.

Here is what I've tried to automatize it :

```css
#menudisplay {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

#menudisplay ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menudisplay ul li {
    padding: 110px;
}

.style {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyle.css" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic SC|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>

  <video autoplay muted class="style">
    <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    The video is not working.
  </video>

  <div id="menudisplay">

    <img class="style" src="./img.jpg">

    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="./ex1.html">EXEMPLE 1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="./ex2.html">EXEMPLE 2</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>


  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var video = document.getElementById("video");
      var menudisplay = document.getElementById("menudisplay");

      if (video.ended == true) {
        menudisplay.style.display = "block";
        video.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        menudisplay.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

I use Visual Studio Code and my web browser is Edge.
Thank you in advance, I'm really stuck !

Comment: Check the following docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I added both an evenlistener for DOMContentLoaded (for making sure that the document has been loaded) and for the video ending.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var menudisplay = document.getElementById("menudisplay");

  video.addEventListener('ended', e => {
    menudisplay.style.display = "block";
    video.style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
#menudisplay {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

#menudisplay ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#menudisplay ul li {
  padding: 110px;
}

.style {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyle.css" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic SC|Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <video autoplay muted class="style" id="video">
    <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm">
    <p>The video is not working.</p>
  </video>
  <div id="menudisplay">
    <img class="style" src="./img.jpg">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="./ex1.html">EXEMPLE 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="./ex2.html">EXEMPLE 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work,

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
const menuDisplay = document.querySelector('#menudisplay');
video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
    menuDisplay.style.display = 'block';
    //you can also do things with 'event' obj 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

Answer (score 0):

you can use this script to detect when the video finished and what should be displayed after that:

video not supported

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
         document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
               function myHandler(e) {
           // What you want to do after the event
          }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

like the others.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var videoPl = document.getElementById("menudisplay");

video.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  videoPl.style.display = 'block'
})
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onended.asp