# Play audio file one after another in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, socket.io, html5-audio

I am trying to play audio files but the thing is the source of audio is coming from socket. When multiple audio's URL come from **socket** one after another in some **fraction of seconds** then **latest URL** is playing but I want to play the audio file one after another

Here below is the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("newsAudioStream", async (AudioStream) => {
      if (speech && settings.rFeeds) {
        const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(AudioStream);
        const arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer;
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        pollyPlayerRef.current.src = url;
        pollyPlayerRef.current.load();
        pollyPlayerRef.current.play();
      }
    });
    return () => socket.off("newsAudioStream");
}, [settings.rFeeds, speech]);
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe push the AudioStreams in a queue and then write a queue consumer that decides when to play a AudioStream(or skip it in case you want to).

Queue would give you full control over these things. To know if a currently playing video has ended you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880950/1109657
Consume next item from queue after the `ended` event has fired.

Comment: Can you please provide any code example for queue?

Comment: Queue can be an array that you are looping over(maintaining the currently iterated item index in some other variable). Increment the index when current video ends.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. Can you please upvote this question so that others can get benefits from it.