# How do I implement a simple audio playlist in HTML5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have a list of files in mp3 format and in ogg format (both formats for each). and I want to have a playlist that goes from one song to the other as in a normal playlist. But also allows the user click on whatever song they like to re-initiate play.

I would like to learn how to build this in HTML5, with a customizable skin and using as little outside languages as possible. (no flash for example...but javascript, PHP, MySQL/XML at most)

What are the simple ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question:

[HTML 5 video or audio playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist)

Tutorial about html5  element:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-audio-radio-player/