# Where are the events for the video element in GWT

Tags: events, html, gwt, video

I'm trying to use HTML5 and the "Video" element. I'm would like to implement some kind of simple player using GWT and I'm looking for playback events. More specifically when a video has finished.

From the GWT documentation, there is no events (not in Video or VideoElement). So, do I have to implement my own timer and check the status (VideoElement.hasEnded) and fire my own event?

The closer I found to what I'm looking for is:
[HTML 5 video or audio playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist)

Also, I found this interesting library as well that does some of the stuff I'm interested in:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html5-video/.

thanks.

Comment: I'm using a timer so far and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

You "just" have to wait a bit: http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1385804/

Comment: For now, I made my own system. I just didn't want to code everything. I thought that those events would be kind of "included" since it's so basic. Thanks for the link.