# In html5 video tag is it possible to play media resources listed in source tags sequentially?

Tags: html5-video

The problem is, my videos are hosted on a video site, longer videos will be divided into several parts. I want to play these clips in html5 video tag on my own site, is it possible to play media resources listed in source tags sequentially?

I googled and got to the w3c's html5 video spec page, find an attribute named *startOffsetTime*, I tried to assign value for this attribute to each media resource as suggested in the spec, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the next clip when JavaScript's `onend` event is triggered.

Check out [markcial's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist/2552131#2552131) in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist).

Comment: Thanks, @uncollected! I've read markcial's answer, but I'm still wondering, isn't there any workaround to let the clips share their timeline? I mean being able to seek between these clips.