# How to calculate the total duration of a set of tracks using the HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am building a custom audio player (planning phase for now :) ), and I am stuck with this. I wanna calculate the total duration of all my songs in the beginning. I know that I need to load each song in order to know its duration. If I set the src attribute for instance for the first song I get the duration of it with the loadedmetadata event handler. But how to get the sum of them all? Do I need to load each one individually? Do I need to set the src attr of the audio element for each song I have in the list? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with HTML5 alone, since there is no specification for playlists or something like that. I think you'll need to execute some server-side script that gets the duration of the audios and load the result into the site. You may also use Javascript to load all items in a sequence (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist) and get the duration out of that, however this is going to take some time.

Answer (score 1):

I was here yesterday because I needed to solve this exact same problem and, of course, StackOverflow was top of the search results - even for this four year-old unanswered questions.  Alas my searches for a native JS solution proved fruitless, though I tried several different suggestions from here and there, so here's what I eventually came up with myself...

```
function tracksTotalLength(Tracklist) {
    var tempAudio = document.createElement('audio'),
        L = Tracklist.length,
        i = 0, // iterator
        TTL = 0, // TotalTrackLength
        flag = true;

    // set media-type and mute (belt and braces)
    tempAudio.type = 'audio/mpeg';
    tempAudio.muted = true;

    tempAudio.addEventListener(
        'durationchange',
        function(e) {
            TTL += e.target.duration;
            /* DEBUG ONLY */ console.log('TTL:',TTL);
            recursiveUpdater(i++);
        },
        false
    );

    function recursiveUpdater(ii) {
        if (!isNaN(TTL) && ii < L) {
            tempAudio.src = Tracklist[ii];
            // fires recursiveUpdater()
            // via 'durationchange' event
        } else {
            // sometimes not all values are caught
            // and TTL = NaN, so
            // reset and have another run at it
            if (isNaN(TTL) && flag) {
                i = 0;
                flag = false;
                recursiveUpdater(i);
            } else (
                // but you can't recurse all day so
                // remove tempAudio
                tempAudio = null;
                // if it hasn't caught return false
                return (!isNaN(TTL) : TTL : false);
            }
        }
    }
    return recursiveUpdater(i);
}

var tracks = [
    'path/to/track01.mp3',
    'path/to/track02.mp3',
    'path/to/track03.mp3',
    /*...etc... */ 
];
var totalLength = tracksTotalLength(tracks);
//=> totalLength = seconds (float) or false
```

The function `tracksTotalLength()` returns the total time of the list in seconds which can then be rounded into hh:mm:ss as per this classic [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313008/4746328).

The 'durationchange' is fired when the metadata is loaded or changed.  More on this at [Media Events (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events)

Tested in latest Firefox and Chromium browsers on Lubuntu 14.04 with tracklists of 5-50 items.

Hope this helps someone, or at least encourages a true JS guru to come up with a better routine.