# Play multiple music using audio tag

Tags: html, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML 5 video or audio playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist)

I want to play audio at the background of the page.

```
<audio autoplay="true" loop="true" src="track1.mp3" ></audio>
```

But I want to play more than one track.

By doing this, `m3u` playlist is not working :

```
<audio autoplay="true" loop="true" src="playlist.m3u" ></audio>
```

and this also :

```
<audio autoplay="true" loop="true" >
<source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="track2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

How possible I play a list of track by using the `audio` tag?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist

Comment: The example you shown me, there is a playlist displayed, and only change track when clicked?