# Playing m3u8 on any devices (IOS, Android, PC)

Tags: video.js

is it possible to play a m3u8 file using video.js on any devices?
So far, I am only able to play them on Android or IOS. Want to play them on PC as well.

This is what I am using but no luck.

Thanks for your help

```
<source src="http://www.domaine-name.com/name/playlist.m3u8" type='video/mp4'>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U):

> An M3U file is a plain text file that specifies the locations of one
>   or more media files. The file is saved with the "M3U" or "m3u"
>   filename extension. Each entry carries one specification. The
>   specification can be any one of the following:
>
> - an absolute local pathname; e.g., C:\My Music\Heavysets.mp3
> - a local pathname relative to the M3U file location; e.g.    Heavysets.mp3
> - a URL.

As M3U only stores the multimedia items locations, you should parse it and play them using the proper audio/video playback lib.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist)

**EDIT:** The link in the comment points to another m3u, you just should get the link to the multimedia files:

Content of first m3u:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=613798
http://tveurope1.zion3media.com:1935/demoweb1/mystream/playlist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=506379083
```

When you follow that link you will get a playlist like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1343
#EXTINF:11,
media_1343.ts?wowzasessionid=506379083
#EXTINF:12,
media_1344.ts?wowzasessionid=506379083
#EXTINF:9,
media_1345.ts?wowzasessionid=506379083
```

Example of multimedia resource from playlist:

```
http://tveurope1.zion3media.com:1935/demoweb1/mystream/media_1343.ts?wowzasessionid=506379083
```

Comment: It's actually a live stream. Not video files.
http://tveurope1.zion3media.com:1935/demoweb1/mystream/playlist.m3u8