# How to play a playlist on Firefox OS?

Tags: audio-player, firefox-os

How can I play my playlist (m3u, pls) on Firefox OS?

If those formats aren't support, are there any other formats or workarounds to have your own playlists (instead of only albums and the predefined ones, like highest rated)?

Answer (score 1):

The `<audio>` and `<video>` elements provide support for playing audio and video media in [firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os), but the W3C HTML5 specification does **not support** playlist file formats.

However, you can [create your own media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist) or use any existing media player libraries.

Remember, [`.m3u`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) and [`.pls`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLS_%28file_format%29) are plain text formats. You can request your playlist files with the [Device Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API) or by [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) from within your apps root folder for further *parsing*.

See [Firefox OS Media formats (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: Thanks for the information, very thorough. Maybe I take a spin at writing my own player, if I have more free time available. But does this means that right now you can't play any playlist (other than the build in ones) with the Firefox OS music player?

Comment: @Brutus look, since there is no standardized, technical definition for a "*playlist format*", the Firefox OS music player will **not read** any of those file formats out of the box. To give you an insight, check the [list of playlist file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Playlist_file_formats) at Wikipedia. The guys at Mozilla will follow the [W3C standards and drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/) **strictly**.