# Using HMTL5 to play web based radio streams for 20 minutes each

Tags: javascript, audio, stream

With reference to the code below (copied from [HTML 5 video or audio playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551859/html-5-video-or-audio-playlist))

I would like to do something similar but instead of mp3 tracks have it as music radio streams ( because they are streams they have no duration as they do not end )

Stream would play for say 30 minutes and then move onto next stream and play that for 30 minutes and so on

Can one of you clever people tell me how to modify the code to do this ( or come up with new code if appropiate )

I do know javascript coding but maybe ( and that is a maybe ) have enough knowledge to follow it and figure out how it works from a working example.

JAVASCRIPT

```js
 var audio = $("#audio")[0];
 var tracks = {
     list: ["track_01.mp3", "track_02.mp3", "track_03.mp3"], //Put any tracks you want in this array
     index: 0,
     next: function() {
         if (this.index == this.list.length - 1) this.index = 0;
         else {
             this.index += 1;
         }
     },
     play: function() {
         return this.list[this.index];
     }
 }

 audio.onended = function() {
     tracks.next();
     audio.src = tracks.play();
     audio.load();
     audio.play();
 }

 audio.src = tracks.play();
```

HTML

```html
 <audio id="audio" controls>
     <source src="" />
 </audio>
```

I guess I need to know how to add a play duration for each stream before it moves onto next stream to play